# Reputation lost on downvoting others

Tags: support, downvoting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I observed that my reputation decreases when I downvote answers, why?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2383/i-observed-that-my-reputation-decreases-when-i-downvote-answers-why)

Why do I loose 1 reputation point for downvoting others answers?

I even provided a reason!

I just lost 1 reputation because I downvoted an answer of a user who had not read the OPs question description properly and had thus given a wrong answer!

Why?

Comment: it's only -1, plus you can get back if you work to make the answer better, or if it gets deleted.

Comment: its a rule... most probably to prevent mass downvotes