# Reputation and Reputation loss

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I observed that my reputation decreases when I downvote answers, why?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2383/i-observed-that-my-reputation-decreases-when-i-downvote-answers-why)

Do you loose reputation if you downvote an answer?  Is there a document that shows you the different points you can get for different things?

Comment: Questions about Ask Ubuntu should be asked on [meta]. As such, this question is off topic here.

Comment: And, answering your question, you lose 1 rep if you downvote an answer.

Comment: All your questions are answered in the FAQ which you should have read. But yes you loose 1 reputation for downvoting. That makes it more likely that people have a good reason.