# Why do I not lose reputation when downvoting a question?

Tags: discussion, support, downvoting, questions

I understand why [you lose reputation when downvoting an answer](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/2389/364819), but why not the same when you downvote a question? What is the thinking behind this?

Comment: The actual reason as of "why" http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/90324/213575

Comment: The emotion I feel now is the answer: I feel I'd like to downvote your question (don't worry, I won't) because I hate downvoters ;-) The most common reason people downvote is highly subjective. If you find a question objecively inappropriate  (spam, insult, pointless, offtopic etc) - just flag it. People use to downvote all sort of things that don't please them on websites where they don't have to pay for this just for sake of their own emotional satisfaction, so I think putting a sort of taxation on them is a great invention.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Because, reiterating Oli's words, there's no need to prevent users from "gaming the system by downvoting other question", as there's no point in downvoting other questions to your advantage, unless your aim is for your question(s) to be the highest scoring ever question(s) on the site.